# when editing form , uploaded file is not getting in uploaded field

Tags: laravel, edit, laravel-blade

```
  <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Publication Type</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <select name="publication_type" id="publication_type">
              <option value="Circular"  @if($publicationDetails->publication_type=="Circular") selected @endif >By Circular</option>
              <option value="Law"  @if($publicationDetails->publication_type=="Law") selected @endif >By Law</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Publication File</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="file" name="publication_file" id="publication_file"  value="{{ $publicationDetails->publication_file }}"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
        </div>
```

[image to clearify you about my edit blade structure and where I want file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQl0n.png)

Comment: why you need that there... it is already uploaded to the server... instead you should use an <img> tag and show uploaded image and allow the user to update the image by choosing a new one?

Answer (score 0):

you have `enctype='multipart/form-data` in your form tag ?

```
<form method="post" action="/url" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Comment: No changes when implement your idea ,please provide me any other method to implement

Comment: <form action="{{ url('/admin/edit-publication/'.$publicationDetails->publication_id) }}" method="post"  enctype='multipart/form-data' class="form-horizontal" name="edit_publication" id="edit_publication" novalidate="novalidate"> {{ csrf_field() }}
          
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Publication Title</label>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `<input type='file'/>` wrap your code inside `<form> ... </form>` tag. If you have enough experience you could see that `<input type='email'/>` doesn't work if it's not in between `form` open and close tags. Try it out. It might work.If it's not there may be some css issues. Sometimes css prevent default html actions.

Comment: <form action="{{ url('/admin/edit-publication/'.$publicationDetails->publication_id) }}" method="post"  enctype='multipart/form-data' class="form-horizontal" name="edit_publication" id="edit_publication" novalidate="novalidate"> {{ csrf_field() }}
          
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Publication Title</label>
                 I am using like this bro.can you help me